# implementing a generic semigroup append in typescript

Tags: typescript, functional-programming

Say I want to implement `semigroup` in typescript, a semigroup is something that appends onto itself to get a new `semigroup`.

So the interface would look like this:

```
export interface Semigroup<A> {
  append: (x: A, y: A) => A;
}
```

But say I wanted to have a generic append implementation that could work on object and array for example then I cannot think of a sound way of doing this in type script.

I could go down the route of having different implementations as they do in fp-ts for each type:

```
export const getArraySemigroup = <A>(): Semigroup<Array<A>> => ({
  concat: (x, y) => x.concat(y)
});

assert.deepEqual(getArraySemigroup<number>().concat([1], [2]), [1, 2])

export const getObjectSemigroup = <O extends Object>(): Semigroup<O> => {
  return { append: (x, y) => Object.assign({}, x, y) };
};

expect(
  getObjectSemigroup<T>().append(
    { one: 1, two: 2 },
    { two: "two", three: 3 }
  )
).toEqual({
  one: 1,
  two: "two",
  three: 3
});
```

Is there any typesafe way that I could have a genefic append function that could take an array or an object and then call the correct implementation of getArraySemigroup or getObjectSemigroup?

Comment: Could you provide some examples of how you'd like to call your desired function?  It seems to me that you'd need to already know if it was an object (since the `getObjectSemigroup()` requires the `semigroups` parameter) or an array (which requires no extra argument to pass to `getArraySemigroup()`) so I'm not sure what signature you want this composite function to have.

Comment: A typeclass like `Semigroup` defines a behavior for which different types are considered equivalent, provided they implement this typeclass. Typeclass instances are always specific to a certain type. `append` on the other hand is (bounded) polymorphic, because different types implement `Semigroup` and there is a mechanism to pick the right instance for a given type. So I'd say no, it is neither  possible nor reasonable to implement a generic append function.

Comment: @ftor but what would the mechanism be?

Comment: In Haskell this happens at compile time. In Javascript the prototype system is used to simulate type classes. However, this doesn't work for built-in prototypes, unless you are willing to modify them.

Comment: Yeah, modifying the prototype is something I want to avoid

Comment: The only way to avoid this is to build your own typeclass/instance `Map` structure and a lookup function that relies either on prototypes or `Symbol.toStringTag`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really don't know why you want to collapse these two functions into a single one, especially since for object types you require an additional parameter.  You can use [function overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) to do this in a somewhat type-safe way, like this:

```
function getArrayOrObjectSemigroup<A>(arr: Array<A>): Semigroup<Array<A>>;
function getArrayOrObjectSemigroup<O extends { [key: string]: any }>(
  obj: O, 
  semigroups: { [K in keyof O]: Semigroup<O[K]> }
): Semigroup<O>;
function getArrayOrObjectSemigroup<T>(
  arrOrObj: Array<T> | T, 
  semigroups?: { [K in keyof T]: Semigroup<T[K]> }
): Semigroup<Array<T>> | Semigroup<T> {
  if (Array.isArray(arrOrObj)) {
    return getArraySemigroup<T>();
  }
  if (semigroups) {
    return getObjectSemigroup(semigroups);
  }
  throw new Error(
    'You cannot call getArrayOrObjectSemigroup(array, semigroups), sorry.');
}
```

which could be called in either way:

```
const arraySemigroup = getArrayOrObjectSemigroup([1, 2, 3]); // Semigroup<number[]>

const objectSemigroup = getArrayOrObjectSemigroup(
  { a: [1, 2], b: "hey" }, 
  { a: getArraySemigroup<number>(), b: { append: (x, y) => x + y } }
); // Semigroup<{ a: number[]; b: string; }>
```

But this doesn't seem to be worth very much, since you still need to know at compile time which implementation will get called, so you might as well just use two functions.  If this isn't what you are looking for, you might need to put more information in your question to flesh out your use cases more.

Hope that makes sense.  Good luck.

---

Update: You seem to have edited the `semigroups` parameter out of existence in your question.  I don't understand the point of using the trivial `Object.assign({},x,y)` (essentially `y` unless it is missing some keys) as your append operation on objects, but if that's what you want to do you can change my above solution to the following:

```
function getArrayOrObjectSemigroup<T extends Array<any> | object>(
  arrOrObj: T
): T extends any ? Semigroup<T>: never;
function getArrayOrObjectSemigroup<T>(
  arrOrObj: Array<T> | T
): Semigroup<Array<T>> | Semigroup<T> {
  return Array.isArray(arrOrObj) ? getArraySemigroup<T>() : getObjectSemigroup<T>();
}
```

This at least makes it possible to call without knowing at compile time if you have an array or object, since both implementations require the same number of parameters now:

```
const arraySemigroup = getArrayOrObjectSemigroup([1, 2, 3]); // Semigroup<number[]>
const objectSemigroup = getArrayOrObjectSemigroup(
  { a: [1, 2], b: "hey" }
); // Semigroup<{ a: number[]; b: string; }>
const whoKnows = Math.random() < 0.5 ? [1, 2, 3] : { a: 'who', b: 'knows' };
const whoKnowsSemigroup = getArrayOrObjectSemigroup(whoKnows);
// Semigroup<number[]> | Semigroup<{ a: string; b: string; }>
```

But again, I still really don't understand your use case.  Are you just playing around with semigroups?  The one generated by the above function doesn't seem to be useful for much.  At least the one with the `semigroups` parameter had the appeal of allowing the caller to decide which semigroup to use for each property instead of just using the last defined value.  Anyway, this is probably as far as I can go with this.  Good luck again!

Comment: what if I am working on a tree where each child might be an object or array?  Is this not a good use case

Comment: As for working on a tree, that is part of a good use case but your most recent supplied `getObjectSemigroup()` doesn't help you do that.  You might find it worthwhile to actually write some code that demonstrates how you expect to use this function, and see how you would implement it (in JavaScript first without worrying about types... or without worrying about full type safety anyway).  You will find you need to decide on a mechanism for deciding which semigroup each part of your object is, possibly recursively.  Once you do that you can ask how to make it type safe.

Comment: this is very much me trying to understand why semigroup is important.  i’d really appreciate if you could tell me why my updated example is not as good as the first.  i thought it was more generic.  why was the first example better?

Comment: I don't think I'm qualified to answer why semigroups are important.  I would deem a particular semigroup as 
"useful" iff its append operation is "useful" for the type. Your second example is generic (in the sense that it doesn't care at all about the structure of objects it acts on; it just overwrites the first argument with the second one), but it only does that one thing, and is therefore less general than the first, which can at least be customized.  Again, I think you need to have an associative binary operation you care about and then use it as a semigroup, not the other way around.